# Google Places API (text search) result different from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have gone through the possible related questions on this topic I can find but there is no confirmation or satisfactory answer on what I am asking.

I am using Google Places API Web Service text search in my program.
This is an example of a generated query to the API,
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=D-Marie%20Hair%20Boutique%20united%20states&key=xxx

The results from the API is different from Google Maps.
Eg. when i search for 'D-Marie Hair Boutique united states', the API return 2 records while Google Maps return only 1 record, which match with 1 of the API record.

Is Google Places API using a different database from Google Maps?
If both are using the same database, is there any query parameter I have to use for the API such that it's result match with Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you will get two results by using the Places API.

The [Google Places API Text Search Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) is a web service that returns information about a set of places based on a string — for example "pizza in New York" or "shoe stores near Ottawa" or "123 Main Street". The service responds with a list of places matching the text string and any location bias that has been set.

Lets take your example **"D-Marie Hair Boutique united states"**. So it is only natural for the API to result a place in where there is a Hair Boutique in the United States.

The result will be **Daniella Marie Hair Boutique** and **Christina Marie Hair Boutique**.

So just check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) to know more how the Text Search Service works.

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand. Am I right to say Google Places API Text Search and Google Maps search logic is different?

Comment: Definitely, these are different products and you cannot expect them to work exactly the same way.